# Cannot INSERT data into mysql using php-(codeigniter)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

chat.php(controller)

```
   function chat_insert(){
     $this->load->model('chat/chat_model');
     try{ $data = array(
     $this->chat_model->chat_inserting($data);
    }
     catch (Exception $exc){
    return $exc->getTraceAsString();
  }
  }
```

here controller class i call model class and call .js text data for here....

chat.php-(model)

```
  function chat_inserting($data){
    try{
     $this->db->insert('comments',$data);
    }
    catch (Exception $exc){
 return $exc->getTraceAsString();
}

}
```

chat.js(javascript)

```
function set_msg(){
   var type = $('#txtmsg').val();
   $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
        url: 'chat_insert',
        data: {'text':type},
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert('error');
        }
       });
       }
```

chat1.php(view)
            view code for insert data

```
         <tr>
         <td style="width: 310px">
                <input class="form-control input-sm"  id="txtmsg"       style="width: 350px" type="text" name="txtmsg" /></td>
            <td style="width: 85px">
                <input class="btn btn-warning"  id="Submit2" style="font-family: verdana, arial" type="button" value="Send" onclick="set_msg()"/></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: what is error message??

Comment: Think your error is in passing data. Check that. Above codes have no wrongs

Comment: http://www.formget.com/insert-data-into-database-using-codeigniter/

Comment: yeah.. first i create Formget.com example . that one work... no error ...... but my one is not work.... k.... anyhow thank u ...sir

Comment: check your data passing. Problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a PHP Error in your Controller during creating `$data` in try block. You have to close `array()` and pass required data into it.

```
function chat_insert() {

    $this->load->model('chat/chat_model');
    try{ 
        // Get Ajax Posted Data
        $text = $this->input->post('text');

        // Add msg to database
        $data = array('database_field_name'=>$text);
        $this->chat_model->chat_inserting($data);

        // Return Response
        $this->output->set_content_type("application/json")
                     ->set_output(json_encode(array('status'=>true)));
    }
    catch (Exception $exc){
        return $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

In JavaScript its a good practice to pass the full url of controller in frameworks.

```
function set_msg(){

   var type = $('#txtmsg').val();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '//'+window.location.host+'/CONTROLLER_NAME/chat_insert',
      data: {'text':type}, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function (response) {
          if( response.status === true ) {
             // Success msg
          }
          else {
            // Error msg
          }
      },
      error:function(data){
        alert('error');
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your comment.... but it also not work..... is there any other option.....?

Comment: @amaya have you get any error? have you checked the browser consol?